# Need advice, remove widget for kivy

Tags: python, kivy

New in the world of programming for about months now.

need a help, regarding remove_widget.

please find my simple code for troubleshooting. I've been working on this for about 2 weeks and i cant find a work around to it.

basically this code add a button object and should also remove the obj.
but when i click delete button it doesn't remove the button that was added. Instead its like creating new button and removing it.

Thanks.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv_string = Builder.load_string(''' 

<MScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos: root.x,root.top-self.height
            id: main_add
            text: 'Add'
            size_hint: .1,.05
            on_release: root.add_item(1)
    Button:
        pos: root.x,root.top-main_add.height-self.height
        id: main_del
        text: 'Delete'
        size_hint: .1,.05
        on_release: root.rem_item()
        ''')
count = 0
class AddRem(Widget):
    def addrem(self,add):
        global count
        self.wid = Widget()
        self.list_btn = []

        if add == 1:
            count +=1

        for self.index in range(count):
            self.list_btn.append(Button(text=str(self.index), size_hint= (None,None), width=120, height=50, pos=(200,50+(self.index*10))))

        self.add_widget(self.wid)

class MScreen(Screen,AddRem):

    def add_item(self,add):
        self.addrem(add)
        for index in range(count):
        self.wid.add_widget(self.list_btn[index])


    def rem_item(self):
        self.wid.remove_widget(self.list_btn.pop())

class myApp1(App):
    def build(self):
        return SManage

SManage = ScreenManager()
SManage.add_widget(MScreen())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp1().run()
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code? Does it throw an error? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: sorry i just revised my post. im trying to remove the added button, when i ever I click the 'delete button', the widget is not removing the added button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of add remove buttons I can think of right now, could look like this.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyBox(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyBox,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.count = 0

        self.controlbuttons = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")

        self.controlbuttons.add_widget(Button(on_press=self.add_button,text="Add Button"))
        self.controlbuttons.add_widget(Button(on_press=self.remove_button,text="Remove Button"))

        self.buttons = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.add_widget(self.controlbuttons)
        self.add_widget(self.buttons)

    def add_button(self,*args):
        self.count += 1
        self.buttons.add_widget(Button(text=str(self.count)))

    def remove_button(self,*args):
        if len(self.buttons.children):
            self.count -= 1
            self.buttons.remove_widget(self.buttons.children[0])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```